# Sequence rows by each change in color

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Link to sheet attached , need help with sequensing the rows by "color change"
[SHARED CATALOG WORK FOR STACKED](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bWhKFWpirrAtzwfXjJn4UbrLI-4usqt8dQoz3hbryqo/edit?usp=sharing)

SEQUENCE RESULT "C1-C63" NEEDED FOR EACH CHANGE IN ROW  COLOR ,  IF THERE ARE MORE THAN 63 RESULTS , THE SEQUENCE HAS TO START FROM "D1-D63"  ETC....

I DIDNT KNOW HOW TO DO IT

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach you may try:

```
=let(Λ,scan(,G2:index(G:G,match(,0/(G:G<>""))),lambda(a,c,if(and(len(c),c<>offset(c,-1,)),if(a+1>63,1,a+1),a))),
     Σ,scan(,map({Λ;if(,,)},{if(,,);Λ},lambda(x,y,if(and(len(x),x<>y),x,))),lambda(a,c,if(c=1,a+1,a))),
       map({Λ;if(,,)},{if(,,);Λ},Σ,lambda(x,y,z,if(and(len(x),x<>y),regexextract(address(1,2+z),"[A-Z]+")&x,))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
   LET(a,G2:INDEX(G:G,MATCH(,0/(G:G<>""))),
       b,OFFSET(a,1,),
       c,SEQUENCE(ROWS(a)+1),
       d,{INDEX(a,1);IF(a=b,,b)},
       e,COUNTIFS(d,"<>",c,"<="&c),
       IF(d="",,CHAR(INT((e-1)/63)+67)&MOD(e-1,63)+1)))
```